Relay to read only pulse signal not constant signal
I am trying to find or create a relay that provides power when there is a 12v pulse signal that last less than 1-2 seconds but if it receives signal longer than 1-2 seconds then it should stop or not provide power at all.
What I am trying to resolve is I have car that the BCM sends the brake and turn signal to the lights on the same supply wire. I just want to read when it is a turn signal not a constant brake signal.
It would be okay to wait the first 1-2 seconds in order to determine if the signal turns off or will stay constant then it would provide a pulse signal if the signal received turned off.

a turn signal changes state approximately every 500 ms

This seems like a bad idea in the situation where somebody wants to apply the brakes as they approach a turn.

The break signal will come from a another wire so I will have that separate already.

An on-delay timer will do what you want. If the relay is energised for > preset time the relay will energise. If you get one with a changeover contact you should be able to do any required logic.
Be aware that pulsing the brakes will appear to be a turn signal.

Yes you are correct! I don't know why I was over complicating it. I understand it will thing a turn signal is when I pulse the breaks the same speed as a turn signal.
